# Are pragmas in a cpp of a static library consumed by that library's users?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

After some testing, I feel that they are consumed by the library user even when placed in a cpp, but am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

In Visual Studio, I have a static library StaticLib.lib with StaticLib.cpp. In that file I have the following code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "random.lib")
```

When compiling StaticLib.lib, I do not get any error messages stating that random.lib cannot be found, but when linking against StaticLib.lib with MyProgram.exe, I get

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'random.lib'
```

in Visual Studio 2019.

Is this normal behaviour? Originally I would think that you would need to place the pragma inside a header and have your user (MyProgram.exe) include that header in order to be forced to link against a specific library ('random.lib').

Comment: _Is this normal behaviour?_ I would think so.  Those pragmas are interpreted by the linker, and that only runs when you link your .exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, that `#pragma` is processed by compiler, while compiling your `StaticLib.cpp` file.

The result of it, according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/comment-c-cpp?view=msvc-160, is:

> lib
>
> Places a library-search record in the object file.

THAT is consumed by linker while building `MyProgram.exe`